# Custom search result page in shopware5

Tags: shopware

I need to create a custom search result page for my Shopware site. As I know custom pages can be designed only for detail and list pages.

However, after creating custom list page for my site with the name of “custom_listing.tpl” my search result page is still looks like the default list page of the site. How can I get rid of this default list page template on my search result page?

I tried to change the fuzzy.tpl  {include file='frontend/listing/listing.tpl'} to my “custom_listing.tpl” but that did not work.

Comment: It seems you are customizing a lot pages because you are asking a lot questions about changing the layout. Because this is no answer, i will write it as comment. ;-)
You should try to put all your customizations in one theme so you just can overwrite every template you want to.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to create your own theme/template and activate it in the Shopware backend. Further you need to create your own frontend/search/fuzzy.tpl in your theme folder.

Now let your own fuzzy.tpl extend from the original one like so:

```
{extends file='parent:frontend/search/fuzzy.tpl'}
```

After that you will have access to all the smarty blocks that are defined in the parent fuzzy file and even in the frontend/index/index.tpl of which the parent fuzzy extends from.

Make your changes, deploy it to your localhost or webserver and after clearing the cache the search controller should autoload the overridden fuzzy.tpl with your custom search results layout.